# Selected grouped but not related records

Tags: sql

I'm trying to build a SQL query (should work both on Oracle and SQL server). My tables:

```
CATEGORIES:
ID: PK
DESCRIPTION: Varchar(255)
```

> Example: 1: Fruits; 2: Vegetables; 3: Meats;

```
FOODS
ID: PK
DESCRIPTION: Varchar(255)
```

> Example: 1: Banana; 2: Apple; 3: Egg;

```
CATEGORIES X FOODS
ID: PK
FOODS_FK
CATEGORIES_FK
```

> Example:  1: Banana: Fruits; 2: Apple: Fruits;

As you can see, there's some food that is not related with Categories (Egg for example).

```
ITEMS
ID: PK
NAME: Varchar(255)
FOOD: FOODS_FK
COST: MONEY
```

> Example: 1: Red Banana: Banana: $2,99;  2: Big Egg: Egg: $1,87;

I want to build a query listing all Categories and a sum of its costs, even if Foods is not related to categories (called "Others"), like that:

```
Fruits:  $10,00
Vegetables: $0
Meats: $99,00
Others: $15,00
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

`LEFT JOIN` and `GROUP BY`:

```
select c.description,
       coalesce(sum(i.cost), 0) as cost
from categories c left join
     category_foods cf
     on c.id = cf.category_id left join
     items i
     i.food_id = cf.food_id
group by c.description;
```

I find it a little hard to follow the naming convention for your columns, but it should be pretty clear how the columns are related.

Comment: What about "Others" records (items that its food is not on a categorie)?

Comment: @aseolin . . . "I want to build a query listing all Categories and a sum of its costs".

Answer (score 0):

The key idea is use coalesce on the category to fall others into 'Others'.

```sql
select
    coalesce(c.DESCRIPTION, 'Others') || ': ' || cast(coalesce(sum(i.COST),0) as varchar)
from
    FOOD f
    left join ITEMS i on i.FOOD = f.FOOD
    left join [CATEGORIES X FOODS] cf on cf.FOOD = f.ID
    left join CATEGORIES c on c.ID = cf.CATEGORY
group by coalesce(c.DESCRIPTION, 'Others')
```